# how can i change keys with values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to take words from the user in such a way that the user has to enter the word and write the translation in front of it and with a space, then write his sentence, if his words are in the dictionary, replace those words with his translation but i dont know how can i change them?
for example:
-enter numbers of  you're words to translate:
-enter you're words: say decir
-we Nosotros
-goodnight buenasnoches
-you usted
-tonight esta noche
-enter you're sentence:we say goodnight to you tonight
-i want output like this:nosotros decir buenasnoches to usted esta noche

---

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
numbersofwords=int(input('enter numbers of you're words to translate: '))
for i in range(words):
    words=list(input('enter you're words: ').split())
    list1.append(words)
for x in range(len(list1)):
    list2.append(list1[x][1])
    list3.append(list1[x][0])    
    translator1=tuple(list2)
    translator2=tuple(list3)
translator=dict(zip(translator2, translator1))
finalsentence=input('enter you're sentence: ')
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Please provide example inputs and outputs, and also please give relevant names to your variables.

Comment: Looking just at your question: `{v : k for k, v in dictionary.items()}`, this will change the key-value pair. Also, you can use condition statement inside like `{v : k for k, v in dictionary.items() if k == "<item-to-check>"}`.

Comment: At a very minimum the code you posted will give you a syntax error about wrong string delimiters - please check your usage of `'` as both a string delimiter and an apostrophe :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new dict entry and delete the old one:

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary[old_key]
del dictionary[old_key]
```

or in one line like this:

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```